# Problem with types while using RXjs with React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, rxjs

I know this could not be related to particular react but while using Rxjs Im getting errors from typescript, Im trying to solve this for some time now , type casting/ explicit casting also not working. Im getting type error while trying to use operators on any kind of Observable

```
Types of parameters 'subscriber' and 'subscriber' are incompatible.             Type 'Subscriber<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscriber<any>': syncErrorValue, syncErrorThrown, syncErrorThrowable, _unsubscribeAndRecycle, and 2 more.
```

While using  for ex. map  in pipe:

Observable

```
import { fromEvent, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
const discoveredPeripheral$: Observable<Peripheral> = fromEvent<Peripheral>(
  bleManagerEmitter,
  'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral'
);
```

subscription:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    discoveredPeripheral$
      .pipe(
        map(emitter => emitter)
      //errror for map / any type of operator
      )
      .subscribe((emitter: Peripheral) => console.log('EMITTER', emitter));
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

RXJS version 7.5.5

I tried with many operator , type casting without success/ Trying with observables from subjects as well.

Comment: What is the Peripheral type here? I'm asking because the map operator is usually used on an array to return part of the object for each item in the array. In this case you're just returning the same object which wouldn't really accomplish anything.